# VBA - loop through multiple worksheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that loops through a folder to open files and get important info from the columns of names "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL"by searching for the header and and printing all the info under that header into one excel document, masterfile. It also prints the file name into column 4 and the name of the "Tooling Data Sheet" to column 1.

I have code set that

```
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        With WB
'(2)
            For Each ws In .Worksheets
        ...
        ''''''''''''''''code for all info I need to get from opened file'''''''''''''''''
        ...
            Next ws
'(6)
        End With
    Next objFile
```

**The problem** is that it will loop through the number of `ws` I have in the `Workbook` but it will not switch to the next worksheet. For example, if the first worksheet in the opened file has values 1 2 3, the second worksheet has values 5 7 and the third has values 8 9 10, it will print to my masterfile 1 2 3 then 1 2 3 then 1 2 3. 
Thus, It only open the first one and loops through it the **number** of worksheets I have in that opened file but not through the worksheets themselves. Any ideas on troubleshooting this? I'm stuck.

**FULL CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range
    Dim hc12 As Range

    Dim n As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\2\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2

    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then

'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet

            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets


'            If Not Range("A1:A24").Find(What:="TOOL NUM", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
'                Set n = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet'
                If Not Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
'                Set n = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
'                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
'                If Not hc Is Nothing Then
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "2"
                    End If
                Else ' find TOOL CUTTER on sheet
                    'StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO CUTTING TOOLS PRESENT"
                    If Not Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="TOOL CUTTER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    Set hc = Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="TOOL CUTTER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                        If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 3
                            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                        Else
                            'StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "2"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet


                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

'                If Not Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
'                    Set hc3 = Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                        'If InStr(ROW_HEADER, "HOLDER") <> "" Then
                        If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "none"
                    End If
                ' find "TOOL HOLDER" on sheet
                ElseIf Not Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="TOOL HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    Set hc = Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="TOOL HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                        If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 3
                            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                        Else
                            'StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "2"
                        End If
                'End If

                Else
                    If hc3 Is Nothing Then
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO HOLDERS PRESENT!"
                    End If
                End If
'(5)

                    'print the file name to Column 4
                    StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = objFile.Name

                    With ws
                    'Print TDS name by searching for header
                        If Not Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                            Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                        Else
                            'print the file name wihtout the extension
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = GetFilenameWithoutExtension(objFile.Name)
                        End If
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                    End With

                Next ws

'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
'(7)
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'brings the viewer to the top of the masterfile
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim v
    Dim spl As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
            If Not dict.exists(v) Then
                If Len(v) > 0 Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                spl = Split(v, ";")
                v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                spl = Split(v, ",")
                v = spl(0)
            End If
        End If
        dict.Add c.Address, v
    End If

        If Len(v) = 0 Then
            v = "none"
        End If

'        If Len(v) = "" Then
'            v = ""
'        End If

    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
        'If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function

'(12)
'get the file name without the extension
Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(ByVal FileName)
  Dim Result, i
  Result = FileName
  i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If (i > 0) Then
    Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
  End If
  GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `Range` or the `Cells` method, always fully qualify with the worksheet and the workbook. So your code looks like this:

```
        With WB
            For Each ws In .Worksheets

                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet'
                If Not Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

The last two lines do not state the worksheet to which the range belongs. So instead use:

```
        With WB
            For Each ws In .Worksheets

                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet'
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

In fact, you can refine this further because you don't need to use the `Find` method twice.

```
        With WB
            For Each ws In .Worksheets

                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet'
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not (hc Is Nothing) Then
```

There are other places in your code where you need to add the worksheet qualifier to the `Range` and `Cells` methods.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have a small problem that came off of that solution and I was wondering if you could help with that too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868395/vba-do-not-grab-header-in-range @ChipsLetten