# VBA - do not grab header in range

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that looks for the header "CUTTING TOOL" using a .Find method. It loops through multiple files and multiple worksheets in the opening files.

I have run into the **problem** that when it goes through multiple worksheets in one open file and the column is empty under the header, it will print out the header, "CUTTING TOOL". It does not do this in the initial worksheet or in workbooks that do not contain multiple worksheets. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
'(3)
            'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet'
            If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
            Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                If dict.count > 0 Then
                'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                ElseIf dict = "" Then
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO CUTTING TOOLS PRESENT"
                End If
            ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="TOOL CUTTER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then ' find TOOL CUTTER on sheet
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="TOOL CUTTER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                    End If                  
            Else
                If hc3 Is Nothing Then
                    StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 3), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO CUTTING TOOLS PRESENT!"
                End If
            End If

    ...
    ...
End Sub
    ...
    ...

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim v
    Dim spl As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
            If Not dict.exists(v) Then
                If Len(v) > 0 Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                spl = Split(v, ";")
                v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                spl = Split(v, ",")
                v = spl(0)
            End If
        End If
        dict.Add c.Address, v
    End If

        If Len(v) = 0 Then
            v = "none"
        End If   
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `GetValue` function. When there is no value below the header, the range selection ends up selecting the empty cell plus the heading above it.

You have also not properly implemented the `If Len(v) = 0 Then` from a previous post. You have added it in a region of the code where the value of `v` will never get used.

As mentioned in another answer, you should really use early binding for the `Dictionary` so that the function can return a `Dictionary` rather than an `Object`. In the code that uses the `GetValue` function you are using this:

```
    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        ' do something...
    ElseIf dict = "" Then
        ' do something else...
    End If
```

This is a problem because your code cannot be sure if it has a dictionary or an empty string. But if you always return a dictionary, even if empty, then you can use:

```
    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        ' do something...
    Else Then
        ' do something else...
    End If
```

Which is more consistent. If the code uses `GetValue`, it **always** gets a `Dictionary` but it might not contain any values.

There is another problem with your version of `GetValues`. You are putting the **cell address** into the dictionary as the key but you are testing the **value of the cell** against the dictionary to see if it already exists. From yuor code, it looks like you want a dictionary of the unique values. Rather than break your other code that uses `d.Items` I will change the `GetValue` function so it stores the cell value in both key and value in the dictionary.

```
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    ' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
    ' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
    ' *above* ch and end at ch
    If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.Count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
        theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
            theValue = "none"
        End If
        If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If

            dict.Add theValue, theValue
        End If

    Next cell

Exit_Function:
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean to literally use the line `Else Then` because when I try that it gives back a compiling error saying _Syntax Error_. If I move `Then` down a line I get the compiling error _Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement_ @ChipsLetten

Comment: Also, when I put in the line `Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary` , I get back the compile error: user-defined type not defined..  I'm not sure which isn't defined so I cannot find where it goes wrong

Comment: Apologies, `Else Then` is wrong. Just use `Else`. To use early binding with the `Scripting.Dictionary`, from the VBA IDE select Tools -> References and find the entry for "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and check the box.

Comment: Ah thank you. Okay so I did all of that and then line toward the end of the function that is `dict.Add theValue, the Value` throws back a runtime error: _This key is already associated with an element of this collection_ . I am not sure what that means. Could you help me with that? @ChipsLetten

Comment: Move the `If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then` line of code down to just before `dict.Add theValue, the Value`

Comment: I think there was something in my old Function section that allowed for duplicate values. I really need those duplicate values in there. Do you know what the best way to allow for those would be? That was the reason I was using the dictionary in an object way

Comment: If you have implemented all the answers to your other posts, then I'd suggest a new post with a clear explanation. What is the `GetValue` function supposed to do? You were originally storing the cell address as the key and then the cell contents as the value. But why not just write the values directly to your output cells? Using a dictionary implies that you wanted a list of unique values (with duplicates ignored) but now you say you want the duplicates?

Comment: yes I think i orginally misled the question by saying I needed a unique range. I did not mean to ignore the duplicates, I mean a range that is not consistent. The GetValue function grabs all of the values from the last filled row in a column under a specific header, up to, but not including, the header. It takes those values and transfers them to my masterfile. Does that help to clarify?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895218/vba-change-omit-duplicates-to-allow-for-duplicates @ChipsLetten