# VBA - change omit duplicates to allow for duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

**Explanation of code:**

I have code that takes information from under two specific column headers in opening files and prints them to a masterfile. It prints information to my masterfile into column 3, then column 2, then column 1 based on the number of cells is in column 3. The columns 1, 2 and 3 should always be the same length (spaces included)

I currently use a GetValue function which finds a specific header such as HOLDER, and grabs all of the values under it from the last occupied row up to, but not including, the header HOLDER. It omits any duplicates.

**The problem** is that I need to have the duplicates in the sheet. The reason is that the 2nd and 3rd column values correspond to each other. So if a duplicate does not print to column 3, that doesn't mean there is a duplicate in column 2.

Example:

```
    3  4   
    2  4   
    1  7   
 *next file*
    1  9
    7  6
```

would become

```
   3  4
   2  7
   1  9
*next file*
   1  6
   7
```

*(column 2 is shifted upward due to the omitting of the repeat value "4". The 1 in column 1 is not omitted because it only omits duplicates that are within the same opened file in the same column)*

Thus, I do not get the information I need for that duplicate (using my example, that 2 and 4 should correspond not 2 and 7), and my column alignment is thrown off.

Any ideas how I can go about fixing this please?

**Uses the GetValues function**:

```
'(3)
    'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
    If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
        If dict.count > 0 Then
            'add the values to the master list, column 3
            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
        Else
            'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
            StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "  "
        End If
    'Else find CUTTING WHEEL on the source sheet
    ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING WHEEL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING WHEEL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
        If dict.count > 0 Then
            'add the values to the master list, column 3
            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
        Else
            'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
            StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "  "
        End If
    Else
        'if no CUTTING TOOL header is found on the sheet
        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO CUTTING TOOLS PRESENT"
    End If
'(4)
    'find HOLDER on the source sheet
     If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
         Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
         Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
         If dict.count > 0 Then
             'add the values to the master list, column 2
             Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
             d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
         Else
             'if no items are under the HOLDER header
              StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
         End If
     'Else find WHEEL ARBOR on the source sheet
      ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="WHEEL ARBOR", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
          Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="WHEEL ARBOR", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
          Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
          If dict.count > 0 Then
              'add the values to the master list, column 2
              Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
              d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
          Else
          'if no items are under the HOLDER header
              StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
          End If
      Else
          'if no HOLDER header is found on the sheet
          StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO HOLDERS PRESENT!"
      End If
```

**GetValues Function**:

```
'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    ' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
    ' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
    ' *above* ch and end at ch
    If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
        theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
            theValue = "none"
        End If
            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If
            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If

            If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
            dict.Add theValue, theValue
        End If
    Next cell
Exit_Function:
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
```

**FULL CODE:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range
    Dim hc12 As Range, n As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2

    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet

            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "  "
                    End If
                'Else find CUTTING WHEEL on the source sheet
                ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING WHEEL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING WHEEL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                        If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 3
                            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                        Else
                        'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "  "
                End If
                Else
                    'if no CUTTING TOOL header is found on the sheet
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO CUTTING TOOLS PRESENT"
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the HOLDER header
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
                    End If
                'Else find WHEEL ARBOR on the source sheet
                ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="WHEEL ARBOR", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="WHEEL ARBOR", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                        If dict.count > 0 Then
                            'add the values to the master list, column 2
                            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                        Else
                            'if no items are under the HOLDER header
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
                        End If
                Else
                    'if no HOLDER header is found on the sheet
                    StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO HOLDERS PRESENT!"
                End If
'(5)
                'print the file name to Column 4
                StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = objFile.Name

                With ws
                'Print TDS name by searching for header
                    If Not ws.Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                        Set TDS = ws.Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                    Else
                        'print the file name wihtout the extension
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = GetFilenameWithoutExtension(objFile.Name)
                    End If
                    i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                End With

                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
'(7)
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'brings the viewer to the top of the masterfile
End Sub
'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    ' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
    ' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
    ' *above* ch and end at ch
    If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
        theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
            theValue = "none"
        End If
            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If
            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If

            If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
            dict.Add theValue, theValue
        End If
    Next cell
Exit_Function:
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
        'If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function
'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
'(12)
'get the file name without the extension
Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(ByVal FileName)
  Dim Result, i
  Result = FileName
  i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If (i > 0) Then
    Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
  End If
  GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
```

Comment: `Dictionary` was my *unique* value holder... `If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
            dict.Add theValue, theValue` but you want duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I was brand new to VBA at that point so I did not realize when I said I need a unique range that omitting duplicates would be a part of that. I simply meant not a consistent range which was very misleading. My apologies for that. Yes, I need to include duplicates now. Any tips? @bonCodigo

Comment: `1` As said, if duplicates are needed, a `Dictionary` object isn't the one to use. You may go for an `ArrayList` instead. `2` Why is your key and the value the same? e.g. `theValue`

Comment: It was grabbing the column header whenever the cell was empty. @ChipsLetten helped me fix that issue in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868395/vba-do-not-grab-header-in-range/30874231?noredirect=1#comment49828696_30874231

Comment: Could you help me with implementing the ArrayList instead? I got it to work with the Dictionary but I am not sure what would need to be altered in order to switch it to an ArrayList or even how that works @bonCodigo

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
'(8)
'Get the Values from columns with specified headers
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant
    Dim counter As Long
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
' *above* ch and end at ch
If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
    GoTo Exit_Function
End If

For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
    counter = counter + 1
    theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
    If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
        theValue = " "
    End If
        'exclude any info after ";"
        If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
            theValue = splitValues(0)
        End If
        'exclude any info after ","
        If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
            theValue = splitValues(0)
        End If

        If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
        dict.Add counter, theValue
    End If
Next cell
Exit_Function:
Set GetValues = dict
 End Function
```